What is the etymology of もっと
I can’t find a clear etymology for もっと (“more”). Where does the word come from?

To clarify, are you specifically asking about モット (in katakana) as opposed to もっと (in hiragana)?

There's no reason you couldn't write any word in katakana, but yeah, もっと is basically always written in hiragana

Sorry guys, yeah もっと in Hiragana, I mistakenly thought it was always in katakana.

My etymology resources are limited currently, but from what I can find over here in the Kotobank version of the 日本国語大辞典【にほんほくごだいじてん】, もっと is a relatively recent term attested only since the late 1700s.
Semantically, this appears to be cognate with sense 2 in the entry for もう, as in constructions like もう少し【すこし】 or もう一歩【いっぽ】, meaning basically "more".  However, this is also dated from the late 1700s.  That said, this later date would be consistent with a more-Kantō-style sound shift from もう ("more") + と (adverbial particle) to もっと (trading a long vowel for a geminate consonant).
The もう entry does include a 補助注記【ほじょちゅうき】 section at the bottom of the entry, explaining that this appears to be cognate with particle も.  This would seem to make sense semantically, given the inclusive senses inherent in も.  However, the syntax is a bit odd, since も comes after the thing it modifies, while もう comes before.  Speculating, perhaps this developed from an earlier construction like それも + [thing in addition], where the それ was omitted?  Curious.

This is the best I can find currently.  Hoping others can fill in additional details.
